# running sac2xy returns sac2xy: cannot execute binary file on osx 10.9

Tags: macos, bash, binary-files

I have a Python script for plotting data which uses `sac2xy`, but it gives an error when running `sac2xy`:

```
sh: sac2xy: command not found
```

the relevant part of code is :

```
os.system("sac ./tmp/sac.m")
os.system("clear")
os.system("sac2xy ./tmp/n_"+filename[i]+".am ./tmp/n_"+filename[i]+".xy")
os.system("sac2xy ./tmp/c_"+filename[i]+".am ./tmp/c_"+filename[i]+".xy")

c_amp = []
c_f = []
n_amp = []
n_f = []
fopen = open("./tmp/c_"+filename[i]+".xy")
for line in fopen:
    c_f.append(float(line.split()[0]))
    c_amp.append(float(line.split()[1]))
fopen.close()

fopen = open("./tmp/n_"+filename[i]+".xy")
for line in fopen:
    n_f.append(float(line.split()[0]))
    n_amp.append(float(line.split()[1]))
fopen.close()
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your Python script (or the relevant parts of it)? Also, posting the output of `which sac2xy`?

Comment: part of the code that uses sac2xy: 
>os.system("sac ./tmp/sac.m")
 os.system("clear")
 os.system("sac2xy ./tmp/n_"+filename[i]+".am ./tmp/n_"+filename[i]+".xy")
 os.system("sac2xy ./tmp/c_"+filename[i]+".am ./tmp/c_"+filename[i]+".xy")

 c_amp = []
 c_f = []
 n_amp = []
 n_f = []
 fopen = open("./tmp/c_"+filename[i]+".xy")
 for line in fopen:
  c_f.append(float(line.split()[0]))
  c_amp.append(float(line.split()[1]))
 fopen.close()

 fopen = open("./tmp/n_"+filename[i]+".xy")
 for line in fopen:
  n_f.append(float(line.split()[0]))
  n_amp.append(float(line.split()[1]))
 fopen.close()

Comment: Try `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/sac2xy` or, if that doesn't work, try `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sac2xy`.

Answer (score 0):

It can't locate the executable. Go to a shell and enter:

```
type sac2xy
```

This will give the path to the executable. It's a good idea to specify the full pathname to an executable anyway; it saves lookup time, and it guarantees that you're running the executable you want, instead of some other executable that an attacker may have placed somewhere.

Note that `os.system` is now deprecated. The `subprocess` module should be used for new programs.

Comment: -bash: type: sac2xy: not found ihave got a binary file named sac2xy which itself is not executable, and as i am working on improving already made programme , thank you for the subprocess module

Comment: Do you mean you have a data file named `sac2xy`, which prevents path search from finding the executable of the same name?

Comment: Yes sac2xy is a binary file to be used by the code

Comment: Are you able to run it from the command line? Is it executable? What do you get from `ls sac2xy`?

Comment: cannot execute binary file .

Comment: I am new to data plotting modules , so sac2xy is new to me.

Comment: If you don't give responsive answers, I can't solve your problem. Please say what you get from `ls -l sac2xy` (forgot `-l` above) and `file sac2xy`.

Comment: ls sac2xy returns sac2xy

Comment: ls -l sac2xy reurns -rwxrwxrwx  1 ravi  staff  50334 Jun 12 11:22 sac2xy

Comment: file sac2xy returns sac2xy: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped

Comment: Thank you. From the command line, try `./sac2xy`. In the program, likewise insert `./` before `sac2xy`. The program is in the current directory, and is executable, but the current directory is not in `$PATH`.

Comment: on terminal ./sac2xy returns  cannot execute binary file

Comment: Hmm, then I don't know. It should work. I recommend you start a new question. Focus on `sac2xy` and why you can't run it from the command line. Give the output of `ls -l` and `file`. Ask it on the Unix/Linux site. Good luck.